# Intercept the input element selection inside of an Android webview

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView in my Android app that has a input element for a user to enter text into. When the user selects the input element the android keyboard is automatically displayed and can be used to enter text.

I want to use my own entry method instead. Is there a way to intercept the input element selection inside of a WebView and use my android app to inject the text into that input?

I would need a way to know when a input element in the WebView becomes focused/de-focused and be able to pass a string to display into that element.

Answer (score 0):

To do DOM manipulation in the webview you're going to need to execute JavaScript in the webview.  So to inject & remove your content, you will need to attach onblur & onfocus handlers to the input widget, and control the injecting of your content via Javascript.

To inject content from native code into the JS requires [using JavaScript in the web view](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript) - that link describes how to bind Javascript to Android code.

To stop the soft keyboard from appearing it looks like setting `android:windowSoftInputMode` on the Activity is what you need.

If you want users to be able to use the soft keyboard elsewhere in the Activity, you'll need to to call back to Java code to toggle that property programatically using [setSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setSoftInputMode%28int%29) to enable the keyboard when required.  (I imagine that trying to hide the keyboard when an input receives focus will result in the keyboard appearing, then quickly disappearing.)

Comment: The webview contents is a hosted web app that I have no control over. Is there a way to pass text into the input field by using the same method that that the native android keyboard does?

Comment: Untested, but I think this should work: in your `CustomWebView extends WebView` override `onPageFinished` and then do `webViewInstance.loadUrl("javascript:...`.  In the JS you would then select the DOM element required and add to it's onfocus handler to do what you want.